# Splitting a list into a list of block indices

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list like this:

```
myList=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K']
```

So, suppose I want to process this list as n-batches. If `n = 3`,
the I want a list called `batchIdx` `[(0,3),(4,7),(8,10)]` where each tuple points to the `(start,end)` indices of myList.

`myList` could be of variable length. THis is not simply dividing list into equally sized chunks. Its like using `divmod()`.

Edit: I actually want to create a list that indexes into myList. I'll use those indices in a different part of my program.

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Comment: Do you want to create `batchIdx` or you want to use `batchIdx` to index into `myList` ?

Comment: So you want: `[(0, 3), (3, 6), (6, 9), (9, 12)]` or `[(0, 3), (3, 6), (6, 9), (9, 11)]` ?

Comment: Hi Jon, I actually want to create a list that indexes into myList. I'll use those indices in a different part of my program.

Comment: Yes turns out the question wasn't very clear that `n` would be the _number of batches_, not the _size or length_ of the batches. Now that we know this, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Updated answer based on question edit:</sub>

> This is not simply dividing list into equally sized chunks. Its like using `divmod()`

Here's my solution that returns the indices, that will divide a list of length `l`, into `n` batches:

```
def slice_indices(l, n):
    q, r = divmod(l, n)
    step = q + 1 if r else q
    return [(i, min(i+step, l)) for i in range(0, l, step)]
```

Let's see some indices first:

```
>>> slice_indices(l=11, n=3)
[(0, 4), (4, 8), (8, 11)]
# We get 3 batches, index covers [0, 11] so we pass.

>>> slice_indices(l=30, n=4)
[(0, 8), (8, 16), (16, 24), (24, 30)]
# We get 4 batches, and index covers [0, 30], so we pass.
```

Let's see your list indexed with this:

```
>>> [myList[slice(*s)] for s in slice_indices(l=11, n=3)]
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], ['I', 'J', 'K']]
```

And the doesn't break at the limits of `n = 1` or `n = l`

```
>>> [myList[slice(*s)] for s in slice_indices(l=11, n=1)]
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']] # 1 batch
>>> [myList[slice(*s)] for s in slice_indices(l=11, n=11)]
[['A'], ['B'], ['C'], ['D'], ['E'], ['F'], ['G'], ['H'], ['I'], ['J'], ['K']] # 11 batches
```

Comment: If indeed this is what the OP is asking (I'm not sure) - then `[l[slice(*s)] for s in indices]` is just as nice...

Comment: The goal is precisely to create these tuples.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: NO, this is not I need.

Comment: @user1050648 I've updated my answer, coincidentally I had to use `divmod` you mentioned to get the steps for the indices :)

Comment: And thanks to @JonClements comment I've used the shorter `list[slice(*s)]` to illustrate the slices with your example

Comment: You're right @Chris, both the question and the answer have been updated to address what the OP was really after

Answer (score 0):

```
[(i-n,i) for i in range(n,len(myList)+1,n+1)]
```

Comment: This code, returns a list that create equally sized blocks of n. Not what I need.  I want n number of slices / batches or chunks. So say my list has length 20. and my n = 3, what I need are the start, end indices that can be used to slice mylist into 3 batches, groups

Comment: Agree this code constraints the size of slices to `n`, not the number of batches to `n`